# Chart.js `mousemove` event doesn't register properly if mouse is moved too quickly

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js 4.4.0 to create a chart with a crosshair effect similar to that of the Flot.js `crosshair` plugin.  Following [this YouTube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za2cQFObvWQ), I've produced the following example code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../include/chart-4.4.0.umd.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart_container" class="plot" style="width:50%;">
      <div>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script>
      /* The Chart.js context */
      const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

      /* The Chart container node, used for crosshair */
      let container = document.getElementById('chart_container');

      let chart_data = {
          datasets: [{
              data: [{x:0, y:1}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:1, y:2}, {x:2, y:2},
                     {x:2, y:3}, {x:3, y:3}, {x:3, y:1}, {x:4, y:1}],
              borderWidth: 3,
              /* For the crosshair to work, we must disable other
               * tooltip hover effects: */
              pointHoverRadius: 0,
              pointHitRadius: 0,
              pointRadius: 0
          }]
      };

      /* Chart.js chart options object for the Chart.js
       *  constructor, defined below. */
      let chart_options = {
          showLine: true,
          pointStyle: false,
          borderColor: 'rgba(255,204,0,1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          fill: '+1',
          scales: {
              y: {beginAtZero: true}
          },
      };

      /* Create the Chart.js chart */
      let cjs_plot = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'scatter',
          data: chart_data,
          options: chart_options,
      });

      /* Implementing the crosshair effect previously done
       * using the Flot.js 'crosshair' plugin. */
      /* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za2cQFObvWQ */
      container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
          crosshair(cjs_plot, e);
      })
      
      function crosshair(chart, mousemove) {

          /* Setting `update` to 'none' means the refresh is
           * invisible so that we don't see previous crosshair
           * lines as the mousemoves. */
          chart.update('none');

          //console.log(mousemove);
          const x = mousemove.offsetX;
          const y = mousemove.offsetY;

          const { ctx, chartArea: {top, bottom, left, right, width, height} } = chart;
          ctx.save();

          /* Draw items */
          /* rgba(255,0,0,1) is solid red */
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
          ctx.lineWidth = 1;

          /* Only draw crosshairs if mouse is inside the chart area.
           * Remember 'y' is measured top-down. */
          if(x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom) {

              /* Draw horizontal line */
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(left, y);
              ctx.lineTo(right, y);
              ctx.stroke();
              ctx.closePath();

              /* Draw vertical line */
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(x, top);
              ctx.lineTo(x, bottom);
              ctx.stroke();
              ctx.closePath();

          }
          ctx.restore();
      } // End of crosshair() function

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This successfully creates the crosshair lines when the user mouses over the chart.

The problem is that if I move the mouse pointer out of the chart quickly, the lines don't always disappear the way they should.  They just get stuck near the edge where I moved the mouse out.  This doesn't happen all the time, and it almost never happens when I cross the edge slowly.  It's almost as if the code can't "register" that the cursor has exceeded its boundaries if it moves too quickly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922917/dragging-an-element-with-mousemove-handler-stops-tracking-if-mouse-moves-too-qui) describes a similar problem, but the only solutions offered are to attach the listener to a containing node for the chart, not to the chart itself or to the HTML `<body>`.  I'm already doing that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597832/javascript-mouse-event-not-captured-properly-when-mouse-moved-very-fast) also addresses the problem, but provides only a general description of how the problem might be solved.  I'm going to start trying that suggestion, but I expect it will take a week or two of effort, so I'm posting here in the hopes that someone will have either a better solution or working code to post in the meantime.  (That answer is over 13 years old, so it's a reasonable hope that a better solution exists by now).

How can I adapt the above code to guarantee that the crosshairs vanish whenever the pointer is outside of the chart area, regardless of the speed that the pointer moves?

Comment: You're probably either running into stack overflow or there's debounce implemented somewhere. Is this a real problem or just an edge case that doesn't affect usability?

Comment: It's not strictly a usability issue, but it's a huge aesthetic issue that I don't want to present to users, especially since I know there must be a solution (because it didn't happen in Flot.js's `crosshairs` plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `chart.update('none');` draws the chart without the crosshairs and all that follows in the function `crosshairs` is drawing the actual crosshairs lines.

This means that to remove the crosshairs, your approach counts on a `mousemove` event being fired inside the chart container but outside the `chartArea`, so that the `if` condition `(x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom)` is at least once `false` (which is the only case when `chart.update('none')` is *not* followed by line drawing). That's a very small border on which `mousemove` should fire and that's why it's very easy to be skipped over by a (not very) fast mouse move.

The proper approach to remove the crosshairs would be to also register a handler for `mouseleave` that would only draw the chart and nothing else:

```js
container.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    cjs_plot.update('none')
});
```

Here's your code in a snippet with that addition

```js
/* The Chart.js context */
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

/* The Chart container node, used for crosshair */
let container = document.getElementById('chart_container');

let chart_data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [{x:0, y:1}, {x:1, y:1}, {x:1, y:2}, {x:2, y:2},
            {x:2, y:3}, {x:3, y:3}, {x:3, y:1}, {x:4, y:1}],
        borderWidth: 3,
        /* For the crosshair to work, we must disable other
         * tooltip hover effects: */
        pointHoverRadius: 0,
        pointHitRadius: 0,
        pointRadius: 0
    }]
};

/* Chart.js chart options object for the Chart.js
 *  constructor, defined below. */
let chart_options = {
    showLine: true,
    pointStyle: false,
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,204,0,1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    fill: '+1',
    scales: {
        y: {beginAtZero: true}
    },
};

/* Create the Chart.js chart */
let cjs_plot = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: chart_data,
    options: chart_options,
});

/* Implementing the crosshair effect previously done
 * using the Flot.js 'crosshair' plugin. */
/* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za2cQFObvWQ */
container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    crosshair(cjs_plot, e);
})

container.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    cjs_plot.update('none')
})

function crosshair(chart, mousemove) {
    
    /* Setting `update` to 'none' means the refresh is
     * invisible so that we don't see previous crosshair
     * lines as the mousemoves. */
    chart.update('none');
    
    const x = mousemove.offsetX;
    const y = mousemove.offsetY;
    
    const { ctx, chartArea: {top, bottom, left, right, width, height} } = chart;
    ctx.save();
    
    /* Draw items */
    /* rgba(255,0,0,1) is solid red */
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    
    /* Only draw crosshairs if mouse is inside the chart area.
     * Remember 'y' is measured top-down. */
    if(x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom) {
        
        /* Draw horizontal line */
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(left, y);
        ctx.lineTo(right, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        
        /* Draw vertical line */
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, top);
        ctx.lineTo(x, bottom);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        
    }
    ctx.restore();
} // End of crosshair() function
```

```html
 <div id="chart_container" class="plot" style="width:50%;">
   <div>
     <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you for your help!